# How can I call emergency number programmatically

Tags: android, phone-call

I can call general phone number by following codes:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
startActivity(intent);
```

in manifest file, I add permission like below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/>
```

as android's doc explain **CALL_PRIVILEGED** like this:*Allows an application to call any phone number, including emergency numbers, without going through the Dialer user interface for the user to confirm the call being placed.Not for use by third-party applications.*

And my app is located at **packages/apps**, so it is not a third-party application, right? So, why I still go straight to dial pad not the dialing user interface every time I call emergency number like '112'?

Comment: Check out my answer It will help you.

Comment: none of the below hints is working for me, so i opened a bounty. `android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED` is limited to system apps. `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION)` doesn' t make a differnece to...

Comment: On which device are you working / tested?

Answer (score 8):

The code provided should already work for this, but you need the `CALL_PHONE` and `CALL_PRIVILEGED` permission to dial emergency numbers without showing the dial-pad.

[Android Reference - Manifest Permission CALL_PRIVILEGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PRIVILEGED)

Once that is added to the manifest, you should be able to use the same code using the `ACTION_CALL` instead to direct dial:

```
Uri callUri = Uri.parse("tel://911");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,callUri);
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: dear when i added CALL_PRIVILEGED permission its shows error "Permission is only granted to system apps"?

Answer (score 7):

**Try this**

If you use `Action_Dial` then it will open the `dialpad` directly and `Action_Call` will `call` directly on the specified number.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "198"));
startActivity(intent);
```

**Add permission**  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

**Note: Tested on**

1. **Lenovo K3 Note**(`Marshmallow`)
2. **Motorola** (`Lollipop`)
3. **Micromax A116** (`Kitkat 4.1.2`)

Answer (score 4):

I am also facing similar kind of issue in Android OS 10(Q),

W/Telecom: NewOutgoingCallIntentBroadcaster: Cannot call potential emergency number 911 with CALL Intent Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxx flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.android.server.telecom cmp=com.android.server.telecom/.components.UserCallActivity (has extras) } unless caller is system or default dialer.: TSI.hCI->CIP.sNOCI@AO8

In that case below is my findings and fix. I hope this will help some one.

```
    Intent intent;
    if (PhoneUtil.isEmergencyNumber(number)) {
        intent = new Intent("com.android.phone.EmergencyDialer.DIAL");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:Your Emergency number "));

    } else {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setPackage("com.android.server.telecom");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:Your number"));

    }
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **Action_Dial** because `Action_Dial` will open the dialpad directly and `Action_Call` will call directly on the specified number.

**Note:** Intent cannot be used to call emergency numbers. Applications can dial emergency numbers using `ACTION_DIAL`.

You need the `CALL_PHONE` and `CALL_PRIVILEGED` permission to dial emergency numbers without showing the dial-pad.

Once you have added the permissions, try the below code using the `ACTION_CALL` instead to direct dial:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

[Android Reference - Manifest Permission CALL_PRIVILEGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PRIVILEGED)

Comment: i just want to call emergency number, but not open dialpad, tks

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the Android Documentation for the permission `android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED`:

> Allows an application to call any phone number, including emergency
>   numbers, without going through the Dialer user interface for the user
>   to confirm the call being placed.
>
> **Not for use by third-party applications.**
>
> Constant Value: "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"

The important part: **Not for use by third-party applications.**

Therefore, **it is not possible** using a non-rooted Android OS.

If it were rooted however, you could make your app into a system application and this would work.

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PRIVILEGED

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you a heads up, it has become standard especially in Europe for all the emergency number to be automatically routed to: 112. To change this to the different emergency numbers in the world, (since the US for example uses 911) I would use the locale settings to get the current region and then call the emergency number specific to that region.

This can be easily achieved through an if statement.

Then use the code below to implement the calling part:

```
Uri callUri = Uri.parse("tel://emergencyNum");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,callUri);
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

As you mentioned, don't forget to add the permissions to the manifest file, otherwise the app will crash:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi! How do you get emergency(particularly ambulance number ) for specific country? Do you have switch/map with pairs country=phone or you get phone number from Android framework ? Thank you!

Comment: There are several APIs which can do this for you. The following is one of them: https://www.programmableweb.com/api/emergency-number

Comment: Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

Emergency numbers require the user to fire the action himself.

Dialing 911 (US) is a mistake who could generate fees.

I worked around a project who calls 911 when a user falls. Obviously, it was for elderlies and/or injured people. When he falls, the emergency number is called.

You now have two options to simulate the "human action" as a basic AI.

1) Perform a click on the call button once dialed

Look at Phone app Android Samples and set an alarm which perform a clic on the call button. The sample will give you the button id.

2) Ask for permission (and the user HAS to allow it) following the API 23 modal : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

The manifest isn't enough in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested a thing which works...

You have to detect if the phone number is an emergency number (they are encoded in the SIM card), then add a '+' at the end of the number if so. I tested with other signs or numbers, it didn't work (the call is done, but it reached not the service).

I put her my code from Orasi (a software for visually impaired people):

```
// Lance un appel
public static void CallNumber(Activity activity, String szNumber) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    if(PhoneNumberUtils.isEmergencyNumber(szNumber)) {
        szNumber += "+";
    }
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
    intent.setData(GetUriForCall(szNumber));
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

GetUriForCall encodes the signs. I put also the code here:

```
// Retourne une URI pour appel téléphonique, avec adaptation encodage caratères
public static Uri GetUriForCall(String szNumber) {
    String szOutNumber = szNumber.replace("*", Uri.encode("*")).replace("#",Uri.encode("#"));
    return Uri.parse("tel:" + szOutNumber);
}
```

I'm in France, and I've tested with the '112', which is seen as an emergency number. It works !

Note that the usual emergencies numbers, which are 15 (SAMU), 18 (Fire Department) and 17 (Police) are not seen as emergencies numbers by the SIM card, and work as normal numbers. Moreover, 911 is seen as one, even if you can't call someone with this number here...

So I think it's important to test the number before adding a '+'.
Note also I encode '*' and '#', not '+', so it may explain why this is not working with these signs.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

No permission required in manifest. Call emergency dialer intent:

```
try {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent("com.android.phone.EmergencyDialer.DIAL");
    callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:112")); // < Optional, will prompt number for user
    startActivity(callIntent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // in case something went wrong ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + any  number));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

permission need the `CALL_PHONE` and `CALL_PRIVILEGED` is needed for calling.
   It works.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the source code line 212-219 of Android framework:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Telecomm/+/ec2a7d46128888f025dc3248d083043b978a46f4/src/com/android/server/telecom/NewOutgoingCallIntentBroadcaster.java

Answer (score 0):

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/>` is only granted to system apps. You need to install your app as system app. [Here](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-any-app-as-system-app-on-android/) is a decent tutorial to do that.

Answer (score 0):

try this following code you'll get your answer

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:112");
                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Can't make a call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

and for permission you can give

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```